# "This interaction failed" Discord bot with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I get "This Interaction failed" in this code:

```
class SimpleView(discord.ui.View):
@discord.ui.button(label="✔️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
async def approve(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Approved!", ephemeral=True)

@discord.ui.button(label="❌", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
async def deny(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Denied!")

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member):
 view = SimpleView()

 role_name = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Test")

 approve_channel_id = 1158716789103013898
 approve = member.guild.get_channel(approve_channel_id)

 if approve is not None:
    await member.add_roles(role_name)
    await approve.send(f"{member} joined the server! Do you Approve?", view=view)
    await view.wait()
 else:
    print(f"Channel with ID {approve_channel_id} not found!")
```

What im trying to do is when someone joins the server he gets a specific role and in an Admin-only channel a message to be sent with 2 buttons one that accepts the user to be in the server and another to deny. But whan i press a button i get "This Interaction failed" and no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a timeout error here.

```
class SimpleView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="✔️", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def approve(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button,custom_id="accept"):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Approved!", ephemeral=True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="❌", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def deny(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button,custom_id="denied"):
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Denied!")
```

Also if you want to you can make your button respond even after the bot has been restarted:

In your `on_ready()` function add `bot.add_view(SimpleView())` without any awaiting.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.add_view(SimpleView())
```